# Bootstrap and Rails' collection_check_boxes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

Per the Bootstrap 5 documentation, the label needs to be after the checkbox tag to create button-like checkboxes or radios.  Taken directly from the documentation [here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/forms/checks-radios/#outlined-styles):

```
<input type="radio" class="btn-check" name="options-outlined" id="danger-outlined" autocomplete="off">
<label class="btn btn-outline-danger" for="danger-outlined">Danger radio</label>
```

In Rails, there is the collection_check_boxes, where you can define the label's and check_box's classes.  However, it renders with the check_box first, then the label second.

The Bootstrap behavior is that if the label is first, you can't tell the object is checked or not when using the outline styling.  However when the label is defined second like the radio example above, you can tell the object is selected.

In Rails, it seems to render the below with the label first rather than second.  So I can't tell the the object is selected or not.

```
= f.collection_check_boxes :pronouns, pronoun_list, :first, :last do |b|
    = b.label(:"data-value" => b.value, class: "btn btn-outline-primary btn-lg mb-2 w-25") { b.check_box(class: "btn-check") + b.text }
```

Here is my helper method that the collection calls:

```
def pronoun_list
        [
            ["He/Him/His", "He/Him/His"],
            ["She/Her/Hers", "She/Her/Hers"],
            ["They/Them/Their", "They/Them/Their"],
            ["Zie/Zim/Zir", "Zie/Zim/Zir"],
            ["Sie/Sie/Hir", "Sie/Sie/Hir"],
            ["Ey/Em/Eir", "Ey/Em/Eir"],
            ["Ve/Ver/Vis", "Ve/Ver/Vis"],
            ["Tey/Ter/Tem", "Tey/Ter/Tem"],
            ["E/Em/Eir", "E/Em/Eir"],
            ["Prefer not to disclose", "Prefer not to disclose"]            
        ]
    end
```

For now, I am able to get it to work as I want to by individually calling each checkbox in the code.  This manually coding of it also allows me to add the proper layout via Bootstrap as below:

```
%fieldset.border.border-dark.p-2
        %legend Pronouns
        .row 
            .col-md-4.d-grid.mb-3.d-block
                = f.check_box :pronouns_he, class: "btn-check"
                = f.label :pronouns_he, "He/Him/His", class: "btn btn-outline-primary btn-lg text-start"
            
            .col-md-4.d-grid.mb-3.d-block
                = f.check_box :pronouns_she, class: "btn-check"
                = f.label :pronouns_she, "She/Her/Hers", class: "btn btn-outline-primary btn-lg text-start"
            .col-md-4.d-grid.mb-3.d-block
                = f.check_box :pronouns_they, class: "btn-check"
                = f.label :pronouns_they, "They/Them/Their", class: "btn btn-outline-primary btn-lg text-start"
            .col-md-4.d-grid.mb-3.d-block
                = f.check_box :pronouns_zie, class: "btn-check"
                = f.label :pronouns_zie, "Zie/Zim/Zir", class: "btn btn-outline-primary btn-lg text-start"
            
            .col-md-4.d-grid.mb-3.d-block
                = f.check_box :pronouns_sie, class: "btn-check"
                = f.label :pronouns_sie, "Sie/Sie/Hir", class: "btn btn-outline-primary btn-lg text-start"
            
            .col-md-4.d-grid.mb-3.d-block
                = f.check_box :pronouns_ey, class: "btn-check"
                = f.label :pronouns_ey, "Ey/Em/Eir", class: "btn btn-outline-primary btn-lg text-start"
            
            .col-md-4.d-grid.mb-3.d-block
                = f.check_box :pronouns_ve, class: "btn-check"
                = f.label :pronouns_ve, "Ve/Ver/Vis", class: "btn btn-outline-primary btn-lg text-start"
            
            .col-md-4.d-grid.mb-3.d-block
                = f.check_box :pronouns_tey, class: "btn-check"
                = f.label :pronouns_tey, "Tey/Ter/Tem", class: "btn btn-outline-primary btn-lg text-start"
            
            .col-md-4.d-grid.mb-3.d-block
                = f.check_box :pronouns_e, class: "btn-check"
                = f.label :pronouns_e, "E/Em/Eir", class: "btn btn-outline-primary btn-lg text-start"
            
            .col-md-4.d-grid.mb-3.d-block
                = f.check_box :pronouns_nondisclose, class: "btn-check"
                = f.label :pronouns_nondisclose, "Prefer not to disclose", class: "btn btn-outline-primary btn-lg text-start"
        
        .form-group.mb-4
            = f.label :pronouns, "Other Pronouns"
            = f.text_field :pronouns, class: "form-control border border-dark"
```

[image: Screenshot showing layout of checkboxes buttons]

Any suggestions on how to reduce the code and use the collection_check_boxes instead?

Here's an updated code after the person's answer below:

```
%fieldset.border.border-dark.p-2.mb-4
        %legend Pronouns
        .row.mb-4
            = f.collection_check_boxes :pronouns, pronoun_list, :itself, :itself, {include_hidden: false} do |b|
                .col-md-4.d-grid.d-block.mb-2
                    = b.check_box(class: "btn-check")
                    = b.label(:"data-value" => b.value, class: "btn btn-outline-dark text-start btn-lg") 

        .form-group.mb-4
            = f.label :pronouns_other, "Other Pronouns"
            = f.text_field :pronouns_other, class: "form-control border border-dark"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I belive you copied the example from the documentation which is intended to show how you would place the checkbox inside the label element. If thats not what you want then don't put the checkbox inside the block:

```
= f.collection_check_boxes :pronouns, pronoun_list, :first, :last do |b|
  .col-md-4.d-grid.mb-3.d-block
    = b.label(:"data-value" => b.value, class: "btn btn-outline-primary btn-lg mb-2 w-25") 
    = b.check_box(class: "btn-check")
```

Also since the pairs in the array are identical you can just use a normal array and the `Object#itself` method:

```
= f.collection_check_boxes :pronouns, pronoun_list, :itself, :itself do |b|
  .col-md-4.d-grid.mb-3.d-block
    = b.label(:"data-value" => b.value, class: "btn btn-outline-primary btn-lg mb-2 w-25") 
    = b.check_box(class: "btn-check")
```

```
def pronoun_list
  [
    "He/Him/His",                                                                                                           
    "She/Her/Hers",                                                                                                         
    "They/Them/Their",                                                                                                      
    "Zie/Zim/Zir",                                                                                                          
    "Sie/Sie/Hir",                                                                                                          
    "Ey/Em/Eir",                                                                                                            
    "Ve/Ver/Vis",                                                                                                           
    "Tey/Ter/Tem",                                                                                                          
    "E/Em/Eir",                                                                                                             
    "Prefer not to disclose"
  ] 
end
```

Comment: Thanks, this really helped me out, though I did have to change :pronouns to :pronouns_other for the Other text field in order to get the collection's items to even commit to the database.  It always committed with a blank item in the array as the first one, so I added include_hidden: false.  The only problem now is in the Edit view, the items that are selected aren't in their selected states.